# Is possible to write XSS vulnerable flask web app?

Tags: security, flask, web, xss, script-tag

I'm trying to write a stored xss vulnerable flask web app. My app receive input via this input field `<input type="text" name="content" id="content" />` and then show User input into an HTML table.
I tried to insert a script like `<script>alert(1)</script>` into the input field but when it is shown, the script isn't triggered.
Here is my code:
**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
  date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

  def __repr__(self):
    return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    task_content = request.form['content']
    new_task = Todo(content=task_content)
    try:
      db.session.add(new_task)
      db.session.commit()
      return redirect('/')
    except:
      return "There was an issue adding your task"
  else:
    tasks = Todo.query.order_by(Todo.date_created).all()
    return render_template("index.html", tasks=tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block head %}
<title>Task Master</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class="content">
  <h1 style="text-align: center">Task Master</h1>
  {% if tasks|length < 1 %}
  <h4 style="text-align: center">There are no tasks. Create one below!</h4>
  {% else %}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Added</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    {% for task in tasks %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ task.content }}</td>
      <td>{{ task.date_created.date() }}</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/delete/{{task.id}}">Delete</a>
        <br />
        <a href="/update/{{task.id}}">Update</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
  {% endif %}

  <div class="form">
    <form action="/" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="content" id="content" />
      <input type="submit" value="Add Task" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}"
    >
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbVlkWml6LXdidjlTMFdZb1FKMGFHb25iRDlLQXxBQ3Jtc0tsNlBtLUdmeHNxbHZLN0ZlSXJDZUlQQU5BdTl5ZWFfSU55N3Nob1ZXRmJNNlFvMkpKUFFKNTdfeE9zRFczX1Rxajhmbm16b0M4bVd2LUdubVUwNUZMWklMdHoyTjJRbTA2WFVxSVF6THVPdmd0Q1N0dw&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fjakerieger%2FFlaskIntroduction) example.
This is a screen of the form:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/870tY.png)
and this is a screen of the HTML after the script submission:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Jdd.png)
How do I make the script executable when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask uses Jinja2 template engine and Flask enables automatic escaping on Jinja2 by default.

If you really want to allow XSS, change `{{ task.content }}` to `{{ task.content|safe }}` on your template.

More information: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#controlling-autoescaping